# Reference for flag varieties G/P

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request, representation-theory, schubert-calculus

Is there a good reference for learning about flag varieties $G/P$? I'm already comfortable with the algebraic geometry and the example of Grassmannians, but I am not so comfortable with algebraic groups aside from basic Lie theory.

For example, it would be nice to know which properties of the Grassmannian extend to more general $G/P$ (decomposition into Schubert cells, rules for intersecting classes, the Picard group and the Plücker embedding), so I know what sorts of arguments generalize cheaply and what arguments do not.

Comment: I personally liked [Michel Brion's notes on the topic](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0410240.pdf).

Comment: Over what field?

Comment: Jesko: Thanks, I'll print those notes out now
Moishe: I don't even know the story over the complex numbers, but getting to know what is different in positive characteristic is useful as well.